# PHP CSV regex in string

Tags: php, regex, csv

I have a csv file.
In this, I have a bad character : `arr‰t`. I would this "arret"

I test this : $bodytag = str_replace("‰", "e",$content); doesn't work.

So I search a query which I say : find a word start with "arr" and end with "t" and remplace all the string by "arret".
I find a function to get content between but I can't do my query.

```
    function str_between($str,$start,$end) {
  if (preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start) . '(.*?)' . preg_quote($end) . '/',$str,$matches)) {
   return $matches[1];
  }
  // no matches
  return false;
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `preg_replace('/‰/', 'e', $string);` ?
It works for me, with the string `"arr‰t"`, `preg_replace` returns me `"arret"`

Comment: Sorry, but it works for this preg_replace('/‰/', 'e', "arr‰t"); but not when I do this : $fp=fopen($file,"r");
$content=fread($fp,$sizefile);
$bodytag = preg_replace("/‰/", "e",$bodytag);
echo $content;

Comment: Try to convert `$content` from ANSI to UTF-8, using [iconv](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/book.iconv.php) then do an `echo $content`;

Comment: When I do echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $content), PHP_EOL; The content stop to the first "‰". If I do echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $content), PHP_EOL; I see all content and the word is now "arrt"

Comment: If `$content` is ANSI encoded do : `iconv("ANSI", "UTF-8", $content)` or `iconv("Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $content)`

Comment: With ANSI nothing append. With Windows-1252 I see all csv with "arrâ€°t". I think I should talk to the person which create this file.csv. It means not good parameters exporting.

Comment: By the way, I think it's just an encoding problem, and you'll not need regulars expressions to get an human readable `$content`.

Answer (score 1):

*My 2 cents:* Your file might have encoded characters not supported by the `doctype` specified. `Arret` in French has a small "hat" over top of the "e", as in `"ê"`. Check to see if that can be searched and/or replaced as/with `&ecirc;` or `&#234;`